# Connect to ftp and send a custom command c#

Tags: c#, cmd, ftp, console-application

I wanted to connect with C# (Console program) to a ftp server. I must login with my **username** and my **password**. After I logged in I must send this command `dir! RESETSYSTEM`.

How can I do that?

Comment: what have u done so far? please read [how to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Nothing. I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

The `FtpConnection.Create` method is overloaded. One will take a username and password, and the other will login anonymously.

```
SendCommand(FtpCommand cmd, string param)
```

`SendCommand` sends a commands to the FTP server. The command to send is selected using the , FtpCommand enumerator. You place the parameters in a string object.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FtpConnection ftpConn = FtpConnection.Create("risc.ua.edu", 21, 
      Console.Out, Console.Out);

    //get directory listing
    DirectoryList dirList = new PassiveDirectoryList(ftpConn);
    byte[] data = dirList.GetList(null, Console.Out, Console.Out);

    //parse directory listing
    string list = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    UnixFileNode[] fileNodes = (UnixFileNode[]) new UnixFileNode().FromFtpList(list, 
      ftpConn.CurrentWorkingDirectory);

    //show listing on console
    foreach(UnixFileNode fileNode in fileNodes)
    Console.WriteLine(fileNode);

    //disconnect
    ftpConn.Close();
}
```

for more deatils have a look on [Console FTP in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2998/Console-FTP-in-C)